# A hole when try to make a hexagon from 127 divs

Tags: css

I have 127 divs and try to make from them a hexagon like this

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 127; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: orange;
}

div:nth-of-type(8),
div:nth-of-type(16),
div:nth-of-type(25),
div:nth-of-type(35),
div:nth-of-type(46),
div:nth-of-type(58),
div:nth-of-type(71),
div:nth-of-type(83),
div:nth-of-type(94),
div:nth-of-type(104),
div:nth-of-type(113),
div:nth-of-type(121) {
  clear: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(8),
div:nth-of-type(113) {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

div:nth-of-type(16),
div:nth-of-type(104) {
  margin-left: -40px;
}

div:nth-of-type(25),
div:nth-of-type(94) {
  margin-left: -60px;
}

div:nth-of-type(35),
div:nth-of-type(83) {
  margin-left: -80px;
}

div:nth-of-type(46),
div:nth-of-type(71) {
  margin-left: -100px;
}

div:nth-of-type(58) {
  margin-left: -120px;
}
```

As you see, the first three rows and the last three rows are ok, but in the rows between them there is a hole at the left.

How to remove the hole?

Comment: can you make it executable? it would be easy to help that way

Comment: @AkashJain I tried, but SO snippet displays it incorrectly

Comment: I just copied your code to the snippet :)

Comment: @kukkuz SO snippet displays it incorrectly, not as the browser does

Comment: Pretty sure it's because only blocks #8, #16, etc, are effected by the negative left margins. I don't think there's an "easy" fix to "pull" the other blocks left unless you specify that for every single block. I suggest using JavaScript to automate your styling (it would also get rid of your magic numbers).

Comment: @limits but why does CSS work such way? What's wrong with the other blocks?

Comment: You float all the divs, but only move one per row left, so it does not cause others to move left as well

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ, nop ... yes , it will pull next element untill next reaches parent's boundarie  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VOZoQK margin-left is not quiet position : relative nor transform ...

Comment: Hi @stckvrw, I have the impression you would benefit from having a look at this website, it has many examples of hexagonal grids and other relative functions. https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Answer (score 1):

Use *positive* margins instead of *negative* ones – here it is:

(*Also, made it all configurable with CSS [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)*)

```js
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
for (let i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.className = `cell n${i+1}`
  frag.appendChild(div)
}
document.body.appendChild(frag)
```

```css
body {
  --h: 15px;
  --o: calc(var(--h) * 3);
  --odd: lime;
  --even: goldenrod;
}
.cell {
  width: var(--h);
  height: calc(var(--h) * 0.75);
  background-color: var(--odd);
  float: left;
}
.cell:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: var(--even);
}
.cell:nth-of-type(8),
.cell:nth-of-type(16),
.cell:nth-of-type(25),
.cell:nth-of-type(35),
.cell:nth-of-type(46),
.cell:nth-of-type(58),
.cell:nth-of-type(71),
.cell:nth-of-type(83),
.cell:nth-of-type(94),
.cell:nth-of-type(104),
.cell:nth-of-type(113),
.cell:nth-of-type(121) {
  clear: left;
}
.cell:nth-of-type(8),
.cell:nth-of-type(113) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--o) - var(--h) * 0.5);
}
.cell:nth-of-type(16),
.cell:nth-of-type(104) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--o) - var(--h) * 1);
}
.cell:nth-of-type(25),
.cell:nth-of-type(94) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--o) - var(--h) * 1.5);
}
.cell:nth-of-type(35),
.cell:nth-of-type(83) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--o) - var(--h) * 2);
}
.cell:nth-of-type(46),
.cell:nth-of-type(71) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--o) - var(--h) * 2.5);
}
.cell:nth-of-type(58) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--o) - var(--h) * 3);
}
.cell:nth-of-type(1),
.cell:nth-of-type(121) {
  margin-left: var(--o);
}
```